# Pandas: resampling data with mixed, missing or difficult to 'normalize' dates

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

Im trying to deal with some timeseries data that looks like this. As you can see the data is monthly, but some dates are at EOM, some at BOM and some simply a month name:

[image]

The solution i thought of was: assuming this is monthly data and that i know the start and end dates, i would like to create a date range from that start and end date and re-assign to the dataframe as the index.   however, when i run this code:

```
pd.date_range('11/30/2020','03/01/2021', freq='MS')
```

I end up with this:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2020-12-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-02-01', '2021-03-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='MS')
```

This is starting at December instead of november, so one less row than i expect.
Why is this happening and what is a good solution here?

---

**UPDATE**

doing something like the following solves the problem for me

```
pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime('11/30/2020').to_period('M').to_timestamp(),'03/01/2021', freq='MS')
```

Im fine with that - but are there better ways to solve these kind of date issues?

Comment: `'11/30/2020'` is not a month start (`'MS'`), so the next month start is used by `date_range()`.

Comment: so the 'freq' parameter doesn't telll the date_range function to re-sample to beginning then i am guessing.   which means i should ensure it's the beginning of the month i guess

Answer (score 1):

When you use `freq="MS"` inside `pd.date_range`, pandas understands that you wish to create a range of dates with a month start frequency. The reason why it starts with `'2020-12-01'` is because December is the first start of a month that occurs, given `'11/30/2020'` as the start date. If you wish to include November in your `DatetimeIndex`, you could use `relativedelta` function from [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) package.

To install [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), run the following command inside your console:

```bash
pip install python-dateutil
```

Then to include November in your `DatetimeIndex`, you can do something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

pd.date_range(
    pd.Timestamp('11/30/2020') - relativedelta(day=1),
    #                            ^------------------^
    #                            |
    #                            +-- This ensures that your
    #                                start date is November first.
    '03/01/2021',
    freq='MS',
)
# Returns:
#
# DatetimeIndex(['2020-11-01', '2020-12-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-02-01',
#                '2021-03-01'],
#               dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='MS')
```

Regarding your difficult to 'normalize' dates, you could try using something like this to normalize it:

```py
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

# Your example data
sample_data = [
    "5/31/2011 0:00",
    "6/31/2011 0:00",
    "7/31/2011 0:00",
    "8/31/2011 0:00",
    "Sep",
    "Oct",
    "Nov",
    "Dec",
    "1/1/2012 0:00",
    "Feb",
    "Mar",
    "Apr",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December",
    "1/1/2013 0:00",
    "2/1/2013 0:00",
    "3/1/2013 0:00",
    "4/1/2013 0:00",
    "5/1/2013 0:00",
    "6/1/2013 0:00",
]

# Converting sample data values into `datetime64[ns]`
sample_series = pd.to_datetime(sample_data, errors = "coerce")
#                                           ^---------------^
#                                           |
#                                           +-- Using this option,
#                                               pandas converts any
#                                               "un-normalizable" date into
#                                               `pd.NaT`
print(sample_series)
# Prints:
#
# DatetimeIndex(['2011-05-31',        'NaT', '2011-07-31', '2011-08-31',
#                       'NaT',        'NaT',        'NaT',        'NaT',
#                '2012-01-01',        'NaT',        'NaT',        'NaT',
#                       'NaT',        'NaT',        'NaT',        'NaT',
#                       'NaT',        'NaT',        'NaT',        'NaT',
#                '2013-01-01', '2013-02-01', '2013-03-01', '2013-04-01',
#                '2013-05-01', '2013-06-01'],
#               dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)


# Create your range of dates using the minimum and maximum values of `sample_series`:
pd.date_range(sample_series.min() - relativedelta(day=1), sample_series.max(), freq='MS')
# Returns:
#
# DatetimeIndex(['2011-05-01', '2011-06-01', '2011-07-01', '2011-08-01',
#                '2011-09-01', '2011-10-01', '2011-11-01', '2011-12-01',
#                '2012-01-01', '2012-02-01', '2012-03-01', '2012-04-01',
#                '2012-05-01', '2012-06-01', '2012-07-01', '2012-08-01',
#                '2012-09-01', '2012-10-01', '2012-11-01', '2012-12-01',
#                '2013-01-01', '2013-02-01', '2013-03-01', '2013-04-01',
#                '2013-05-01', '2013-06-01'],
#               dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='MS')
```

**Warning:** the above code assumes that the first and last dates from your data are represented as "parseable" dates. In other words,
if you have a list of dates like this: `["Apr", "5/31/2011 0:00", "6/31/2011 0:00", "7/31/2011 0:00", "8/31/2011 0:00", "September"]`, the above code would create a `DatetimeIndex` that starts at `'2011-05-01'`, and ends at `'2011-08-01'`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a start date that is compatible with the chosen `freq`. So for example `2020-11-01` for `freq='MS'` (month start).

If you don't have control over the first date (but know for sure it is a date), you can "truncate" it down to month start:

```py
t_str = '11/30/2020'

ix = pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp(t_str).normalize().replace(day=1), freq='MS', periods=5)
>>> ix
DatetimeIndex(['2020-11-01', '2020-12-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-02-01',
               '2021-03-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='MS')
```

Note BTW that it's safer to give one date (start or end) and a number of periods (the desired length of your index). That way, you know the length will be correct.

Comment: thanks,  i was able to achieve something similar regarding the start date using: pd.to_datetime('11/30/2020').to_period('M').to_timestamp()